# How to parse output xml from url

Tags: php, xml

I have some url : http://fleet.utrack.co.id/wstj/service.asmx/GetVName?group=2021

How to parse output from that url?
I want to get result like this :

```
$lon = 106.878021
$lat = -6.235802
```

I've tried this :

```
<?php
    $xml = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents('http://fleet.utrack.co.id/wstj/service.asmx/GetVName?group=2021'));

print_r($xml);

?>
```

but the result only

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( )
```

Comment: show your efforts. Also, there's no such value `-6.235802` within that structure

Comment: uh sorry i've wrong about url, i was edit my question

Comment: you want to get the first `log/lat` ?

Comment: i want to get all long lat as array